# the town of Castleford

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, idiomatic-language

From Cambridge dictionary:

> He was born in the small town of Castleford, in Yorkshire.

- I'm not sure whether I understand this correctly.  Is it a town called "Castleford"? Or there is a bigger place like a county or state contains a town called Castleford, hence we say "the town of it" as it is the capital of the state.
- Why we don't just say "in a small town called Castleford"?
- I've never heard "the nation of England" before. But I wonder whether this is a correct way to say "England".

Comment: The village of Littleton, the town of Castleford, the city of Leeds, the county of Yorkshire, the kingdom of England. All quite normal.

Comment: The continent of Europe. [area or place type] of [name].

Comment: Some collocations are more common (i.e. - more *idiomatic*) than others. But note that in your specific example, the main reason for including *the small town of* is precisely because it's ***small***, so it's potentially useful for the reader to know that at least it's a *town* (as opposed to a village or hamlet). You'd rarely see this form used for better-known things (*the **large** city of London*, for example). It's just a "literary device", that learners should probably avoid - it's never *necessary*, and in many contexts it just won't work very well (but it's hard to know *which*).